# Pass parameters to HTTP linked service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline

my query is realted to HTTP linked service (LS) in Azure Data Factory. I have created a HTTP LS and have defined three int type parameters; date, month, and day.
I have using 'add dynamic content' to fetch current day -1 day,month, date and trying to pass these to the HTTP link.
Dynamic content formula for year: `@int(substring(getPastTime(1,'Day'),0,4))`
Dynamic content formula for month: `@int(substring(getPastTime(1,'Day'),5,2))`
Dynamic content formula for day: `@int(substring(getPastTime(1,'Day'),8,2))`

However, this is dynamic content is not working but if I manually pass on year, month and day, it seems to be working fine.

Please can someone idenity the problem with my dynamic content formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You cannot directly use dynamic content to assign values to parameters within the linked service. The static values would only work.
- In order to use dynamic content, you need to pass the dynamic content from dataset to linked service or from pipeline activity to dataset and then to linked service.
- The following is a demonstration where I have created 3 parameters similar to yours:

[image]

- The URL I have used is as shown below (Using this would throw an error but the error would indicate that I will be successfully able to use these values):

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/@{linkedService().year}/@{linkedService().month}/@{linkedService().day}
```

- I have passed the following values from dataset as shown below:

```
year : @substring(getPastTime(1,'Day'),0,4)
month : @substring(getPastTime(1,'Day'),5,2)
day : @substring(getPastTime(1,'Day'),8,2)
```

- When I use this dataset as source in copy data activity, I get an error since URL is not valid. But you can see the URL is built as per dynamic content.

[image]